# How do I say "The night is young" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do I say "The night is young" in German? Here's my attempt:

> Die Nacht ist jung.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can translate directly

> Die Nacht ist noch jung!

or if you wanna say it in another way

> Es ist (ja) noch nicht spät!

Answer (score 2):

Your translation is correct. More common than *Nacht* is IMHO the alternative using *Abend*, it indicates an open end that might cover nighttime as well:

> Der *Abend* ist (noch) jung.